# RubyMine keyboard keymap not working

Tags: ubuntu, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine 4.0.1, I'm try to use keymap shortcuts like ctrl+C, ctrl+V, ctrl+shift+N (search file) and it's not working...
It's stop working after I reset the Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

Check your language. It must be **English**.